# how VAST Tags track referral/traffic source domain?

Tags: xml, server, ads, vast

I'm try to understand, how vast tags, track the referral/traffic source domain ?
thy use any JS code? what kind of?where is the code ? or on which url/tag in vast xml?
want to know about VAST as much possible.

Answer (score 0):

Domain can take an incoming request when you are tracking the impression. Just take it from the headers 'referer'.

**In node.js:**

```
req.headers['referer']
```